# How to print for loop values in textview from JSON array

Tags: android, json

In my code I'm getting an array using a for loop.  The array contains four values.  How do I print the values in a textview?  I want to print these four values in four textviews.

My Code:

```
HttpClient client2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client2.getParams(), 15000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client2.getParams(), 15000);
HttpUriRequest request2 = new HttpGet(SelectMenuAPI2);
HttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(request2);
InputStream atomInputStream2 = response2.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream2));
String line2;
String str2 = "";
while ((line2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {
    str2 += line2;
}

JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(str2);
//  message = json2.getString("message");
status = json3.getString("status");
if (status.equals("1")) {
    JSONArray school2 = json3.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object3 = school2.getJSONObject(i);
        Elementarytxt.settext("");
        Middle.setText("");
        High.setText("");
        Atypical.setText("");
    }
}
```

My JSON Data:

```
{
 "status":1,
 "data":[
         {"title":"Elementary"}, 
         {"title":"Middle"},
         {"title":"High"},
         {"title":"Atypical"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: please check my update ans....

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this. It might help you...

```
String [] mVal = new String[school2.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) 
    {
         mVal[i] =school2.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");       
    }
Elementarytxt.setText(mVal[0]);
Middle.setText(mVal[1]);
High.setText(mVal[2]);
Atypical.setText(mVal[3]);
```

Comment: The method settext(String) is undefined for the type TextView

Comment: errror show   The method settext(String) is undefined for the type TextView

Comment: it is setText(String) :)

Comment: if you want to print simply, change key `title`.
in future if you have 50 or more element than what you do??

Comment: @ Pratik Butani : If elements in the json array is dynamic and each element has to be displayed in different textview then we can add textviews dyanmically and with the existing code run a for loop to set the text for respective textview...

Comment: @  user2699824 : Glad that it helped you.. Plz accept the answer... thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray(ARRAYNAME);
            if (jObject != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  txt.setttext(jsonObject.getString(CREATEDDATE));
                  txt.setttext(jsonObject.getString(SUBJECT));


                }
            }
```

Comment: i want to printlike this

Comment: txt1.setttext(jsonObject.getString(index1));

Comment: @dipali He wants to get value of each element and put into separate `TextView` and also `JSONArray` same key of each value so how to pass key in `getString()`?

Comment: @user2699824 you have to give different key to each element of array.

Comment: txt2.setttext(jsonObject.getString(index2));

Comment: that i understand, but how you passing JSONArray.

Comment: date and subject instead of "title" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope This will Help you..

```
String[] vals=new String[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object3 = school2.getJSONObject(i);
    vals[i]=object3.getString("title");                    

                }
     Elementarytxt.settext(vals[0]);
                                                  Middle.setText(vals[1]);
                                                 High.setText(vals[2]);
                                              Atypical.setText(vals[3]);
```